# BPF print the pid from task_struct

Tags: linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf

I am experimenting to print the value `pid` from the `task_strcut` using `bpf` inside the kernel with the following program.

```py
from __future__ import print_function
from bcc import BPF

prog = """
#include <linux/sched.h>
int trace(void *ctx) {
  int pid = current->pid;
  bpf_trace_printk("val (%d)", pid);
  return 0;
}
"""
b = BPF(text=prog)
b.attach_kprobe(event="<a kernel function>", fn_name="trace")
print("PID MESSAGE")
try:
    b.trace_print(fmt="{1} {5}")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit()
```

Following is the error:

```c
#define __HAVE_BUILTIN_BSWAP16__
        ^
<command line>:3:9: note: previous definition is here
#define __HAVE_BUILTIN_BSWAP16__ 1
        ^
3 warnings generated.
error: invalid operand in inline asm: 'movq %gs:${1:P}, $0' at line 2149017352
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was fixed upstream in bcc with commit https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/commit/d089013e8c6ee0b82d012c1814f822b00695691f. **You'll need bcc version v0.20.0 or newer to have this fix.**

In short, the issue was in the order of definitions. bcc would have its fallback macro definition before the kernel's, hence compilation failed because the macro is already defined. Moving the bcc fallback definition last solves this.